# How can I put a max of 10 random one's(1) in a matrix of 9x9 with 0 and 1 in C?

Tags: c

Any idea how to do it?. i'm new into programming, and for now im stuck at this exercice.

```
for(i = 0; i < 9;++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 9;++j) {

        printf("%d ", rand()%2);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Are the 1s supposed to be evenly distributed in the matrix? Is there a minimum number of 1s?

Comment: Some information is missing. You want a number of `1` equal to 0, 1, 2, ..., 10, but with which probability? Same probability for 10 `1` as for 9 `1` for example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always provide a description in what way your solution fails.

Comment: Max of 10? Pick exactly 10 coordinates at random, and count how many had not been already set to 1.

Comment: Please be clear about how many 1s you want. Exactly 10? At most 10? In which situation is having less than 10 accepted.? Should it be exactly 10 if possible and only in exceptional cases less than 10? It is quite easy to get exactly a given number of 1s, evenly distributed of 9x9 positions, but your question does not clearly ask for that. It is also easy to generate unpredictable number of 1s, with an expected average of 10 in your field. The most simple solution gets you a selected number but tends to put them into the first few rows (@Damien, please, "rows" not "raws"...).

Comment: To my surprise `srand` has been mentioned a single time yet... look it up

Comment: Jordi: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 4):

I would

- Start by creating a matrix with all `0`:s.

  ```
  typedef unsigned char byte;

  byte m[9][9] = {0};
  ```
- Add the number of `1`:s you want.

  ```
  void fill(byte(*arr)[9][9], unsigned count, byte value) {
      for(unsigned idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
          (*arr)[idx / 9][idx % 9] = value;
      }
  }

  int rnd(int min, int max) {
      return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
  }

  // ...

  fill(&m, rnd(5, 10), 1); // this will fill it with 5 to 10  1:s
  // fill(&m, 10, 1);      // alternative if you want exactly 10  1:s
  ```
- Shuffle the result.

  ```
  void swap(byte *a, byte *b) {
      byte tmp = *a;
      *a = *b;
      *b = tmp;
  }

  void shuffle(byte(*arr)[9][9]) {
      for (unsigned idx = 9*9 - 1; idx > 0; --idx) {
          unsigned swno = rnd(0, idx);
          swap(&((*arr)[idx / 9][idx % 9]),
               &((*arr)[swno / 9][swno % 9]));
      }
  }

  // ...

  shuffle(&m);
  ```

This should result in an equal probability for each possible permutation to appear.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P7W98Werr)

---

---

Another option that perhaps is easier to visualize could be to create a basket containing tickets with all the possible positions in the matrix written on them. Then randomly pick tickets from this basket.

- Start by creating a matrix with all `0`:s just like in the first example.
- Create an array with all the positions in your matrix. This is the "basket" mentioned above. You have a `9 x 9` matrix so that's just an array with the numbers 0 to 80. I'll call the basket `picklist` below.

  ```
  unsigned picklist[9*9];

  for(unsigned idx = 0; idx < 9*9; ++idx) {
      picklist[idx] = idx; // fill picklist with the values [0,80]
  }
  ```
- Iteratively and randomly select which position in the above `picklist` you should choose from, while removing the picked positions from the list and leaving only the non-picked position in it.

  ```
  for(unsigned co = 1; co <= count; ++co) {
      unsigned lastidx = 9*9 - co;            // the last non-picked position

      // here you put your hand in the basket to draw a ticket:
      unsigned pickidx = rnd(0, lastidx);     // randomly chosen index in the picklist

      // and this is what was written on the ticket:
      unsigned chosenidx = picklist[pickidx]; // the position gotten from the picklist

      // Assign value to the chosen position
      (*arr)[chosenidx / 9][chosenidx % 9] = value;       

      // Put the last non-picked position in the picklist where the position we just
      // used was, leaving only non-picked positions in the lower part of picklist.
      // This is equivalent to throwing the chosen ticket away.
      picklist[pickidx] = picklist[lastidx];
  }
  ```

This approach should also assure that all permutations have an equal chance of appearing in the final matrix. It doesn't require that you shuffle the matrix afterwards since every position you pick from the basket will be unique and random.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vq78xvodx)

Comment: Why `byte(*arr)[9][9]`? Using `arr[][9]` seems much simpler to me

Comment: @4386427 Yes but since the bounds are set I don't want any mistakes.  Perhaps I'm overly paranoid. :-)

Comment: This works great for the requirement that there be _up to_ ten 1s in the matrix, but if the requirement were _exactly_ ten we'd need to add logic to make sure we're not adding a 1 where it's already been set.

Comment: @Chris If the requirement is _exactly_ 10, then just change `fill(&m, rand() % 11, 1); ` to not include the random component: `fill(&m, 10, 1);` - no logic needs to be changed or added.

Comment: @Chris This code can never place a 1 where there already is a 1. All the 1 are placed in different location and then the matrix is shuffled

Answer (score 1):

This will not result in perfect distribution but should be good enough for a start:

```
int ones_placed = 0;

// pick one of the following 2 lines. Not both!
int ones_to_place = rand()%11; // for up to 10 entries
int ones_to_place = 10;        // for exactly 10 entries

while (ones_placed < ones_to_place)
{
  // Get random position for the next 1;
  int row = rand() % 9;
  int col = rand() % 9;

  // Don't count same cell twice but skip instead.
  if (arr[row][col] == 0)
  {
    arr[row][col] = 1;
    ones_placed ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You will always have exactly ten `1`. Not clear that it corresponds to what OP wants. But the post is ambiguous.

Comment: @Yunnosch Why improveable? With this method, the `1` are equally distributed for sure. Efficiency is not so bad, as 10 is much lower than 91. Note that I am better at probability that at English :)

Comment: @Damien . I was abstracting (possibly too much) towards a) possibly high target  number of desired 1s b) too high expectations concerning the need to avoid a bias to low rows and columns (caused by  `rand()`). I concede that both is beyond the context.

Comment: @Damien do you mean 81 instead of 91? ;) I have updated the answer a bit

Comment: Yes 81... I have to revise the multiplication tables, in addition to English vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

```
int crt_ones = 0
for(i = 0; i < 9;++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 9;++j) {
        rand_no = rand() % 2;
        if (crt_ones < 9 && rand_no == 1) {
          a[i][j] = rand_no;
          crt_ones++;
        } else a[i][j] = 0;


        
        printf("%d ", rand()%2);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

The idea is to initialise your matrix and to keep track in a variable (crt_ones in out case) how many random one's have I generated so far.

Comment: After your edit, the `1` will about all be in the first raws.

Comment: @Damien No, because I put what is randomly generated.

Comment: There is still a good chance that you fill all `1` into first 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an excercise, I am not writing you the code, but instead giving a hint:

1. Initialize the matrix all to 0. Initialize a counter to 0.
2. Randomly select an index into the matrix.
3. Check if it is 0, write 1 and increment a counter. If it is 1 skip to the next.
4. Repeat from 2. until the counter is 10